# How to load native library conditionally based on CPU architecture in android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, apk

In my app I am using a set of native library .And those library are available for different CPU architecture. But the problem is all those library are taking almost 87% of the apk size .

[image]

[image]

I want to reduce apk size for downloading, hence I want make conditional apk based of CPU architecture. How can I do it ?

Comment: To my knowledge, you should create different `flavour` for each `cpu` in your application and use required libraries for each `flavour`. This will give you more then one output `apk` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AbiSplitOptions](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AbiSplitOptions.html).

Example:

```
android {
    ...
  splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    abi {

    // Enables building multiple APKs.
    enable true

    // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
    // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
    reset()

    // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
    include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

    // Specify that we want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
    universalApk true
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you distribute the APK on Google Play Store, pay attention to **versionCode** of each split. Luckily, this is nicely [described](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-APK-versions) on the official site.